# How can I fix my code to accumulate items with same date and username and return time python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I rewrite this code, so that it won't display the accumulated value of the time overall, but the accumulated time value for each user for those days which have duplicate logins.

```
for item in x:
    #x = usage_report.get_login_rec()
    b = item[14].strip('()')
    a = time.strptime(b, "%M:%S")
    c = int(a.tm_sec)
    b.strip(':')
    if item[2:5]:
        test += c
        d.append(test)
        f.append(test)
        t.append([item[0], item[3] , item[4], item[5], str(b) ,test])
print(*t, sep='\n')
```

This is what i get in return:

```
['root', 'Thu', 'May', '10', '00:10', 2285]
['tom', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '01:00', 2300]
['root', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '00:20', 2400]
['root', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '00:20', 2429]
['root', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '00:20', 2514]
['root', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '00:20', 2552]
['(unknown)', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '00:00', 2552]
['(unknown)', 'Mon', 'May', '7', '00:12', 2564]
```

expected output:

```
['root', 'Thu', 'May', '10','00:10' , 10]
['root', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '1:20', 120]
['tom', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '00:60', 60]
['(unknown)', 'Tue', 'May', '8', '00:00', 0]
['(unknown)', 'Mon', 'May', '7', '00:12', 12]
```

x =

```
def get_login_rec():
    raw_login_rec = [ x.split() for x in os.popen('last -F -i -w').read().split('\n')]
    login_rec = []
    bad_rec = []
    for rec in raw_login_rec:
        if len(rec) == 15:
            login_rec.append(rec)
        else:
            bad_rec.append(rec)
    return login_rec
```

Comment: Could you add an expected output as well?

Comment: @user1055395, I've added at the bottom. Maybe there is a better way of dealing with time I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: So, the users should be filtered only by date (without exact time), shouldn't they?

Comment: Yes, they should be filtered by date, but the time that the user has spent logged in should be accumulated and displayed in the last row of the list.

Comment: It will be good if you can post a sample for `x` for other users to work on.

Comment: no problem I've added code for x

Comment: For parseable `last` output, you probably should use `--time-format iso` rather than `-F`.

Comment: Why does the expected output contain `'1:20', 120` and `'00:60', 60`?

Comment: @YannVernier, because I want to generate a report for users logged in at these dates and return the amount of seconds in an integer, but some of them have multiple logins per dates, so I want to accumulate the amount of time a user logged in for those dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want you could create a `dict` object which key is a tuple (, ) and a value is an accumulated sum. In pseudo code it could look like this:

```
userActivityMap = {}
for item in x:
    # I assume item[3], item[4] and item[5] are strings here so use '+'
    key = (item[0], item[3] + '_' + item[4] + '_' + item[5])
    if key not in userActivityMap:
        userActivityMap[key] = 0    
    userActivityMap[key] += <time value>

for item in userActivityMap:
    print(item[0], ' '.join(item[1].split('_')), userActivityMap[item])
```